# It is currently in use by another Gradle instance

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I want to do some basic functions. I'm running/building it in command line. I am referring [User guide](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide.html). And, doing some simple tasks.

When I start to run simple tasks, it was build successfully. But, After some times, it is showing `"It is currently in use by another Gradle instance"` and becomes `BUILD FAILED`. I'm using a terminal for run the task. I didn't run anything at that time.

If I closed the terminal which generate the error, this problem would be solved. But, I know that it is not the solution for that.

Why is this error coming frequently?

How to solve it?

And, Please refer any link to improve my knowledge on Gradle Build system in Android.

Comment: Do you use gradle in _daemon mode_ by any chance? You can check by running command `gradle --stop`. You would expect to either  get output _No Gradle daemons are running_ or _Gradle daemon stopped_.

Comment: @topr I didnt use daemon mode..

Comment: Solution : (That worked for me) 
Step 1. Start task manager find/ verify that there are NOT TWO instances of java.exe running. 
Step 2. Just kill any one java.exe or both and start Android Studio again.
Enjoy

Answer (score 617):

Remove the lock files in the gradle cache by executing something like this:

```sh
find ~/.gradle -type f -name "*.lock" -delete
```

Comment: Thanks!  It worked after I additionally ran 
`find /path-to-project-dir/.gradle -type f -name "*.lock" | while read f; do rm $f; done`

Comment: Today I was back at this question, and this time I needed to `kill -9` a process, in addition to deleting the lockfiles.  The message in the question title was immediately followed by the PID: _What went wrong:
Timeout waiting to lock task history cache (,,,). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.  Owner PID: 4354  Our PID: 9500_

Comment: @JoshuaGoldberg Did you check how and when process#4354 was started before killing it? (I am just curious.)

Comment: I did not, but it may have been left behind somehow during a failed build. (Failed builds are common, and leftover processes are very rare.)

Comment: Here is little scriptlet to kill daemons:

ps -ef | grep [G]radleDaemon | awk '{ print "Killing gradle daemon with pid " $2; system("kill " $2); }'

Comment: Thanks for sharing that command, I had never had that problem before and after remove the lock files for gradle, I was able to run my server again. This should be marked as "Best answer"

Comment: `find ~/.gradle -type f -name "*.lock" -exec rm {} \;`

Comment: @shashank-chandak in a bash shell (Terminal or Cygwin)

Comment: I got this error after deletion of lock files : org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceCreationException: Could not create service of type FileHasher using BuildSessionScopeServices.createFileSnapshotter().

Comment: @Nininea This maybe of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45177977/gradle-could-not-create-service-of-type-filehasher/46094804 ?

Comment: Now I get an error: **Unable to start the daemon process**

Comment: Close Android Studio and probably unload Java from memory to remove files.

Answer (score 70):

Sometimes fast way comes in a non-elegant deal, there we go:

Find first the # of all gradle process running on

```
ps -A | grep gradle
```

After that, get the IDs, Kill 'em all one by one

```
sudo kill -9 <process ID>
```

Now you're good ;-)

Comment: can also do `gradle --stop`

Comment: `ps ax | grep gradle | cut -f 2 -d " " | xargs kill` this worked for me. Might have to adjust the "cut" if ps output differs

Answer (score 41):

```
gradlew --stop
```

I had a similar error, running the above command worked for me.

Comment: for me, i ran `./gradlew --stop` on another project, yeah i opened 2 android studio project, then the project i want to build worked

Answer (score 33):

I was stuck with this error and had to blow away the contents of my user's `.gradle/caches/` folder and the contents of my project's `.gradle/` folder to get going again.

Not sure what caused it, possibly a failed build that kept these files in a locked state?

Comment: This problem is noted here -- https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2795 -- While the gradle bug exists, I think this is the best solution.

Comment: Actually I had success just deleting ~/.gradle/caches/* without touching the project's .gradle directory.

Comment: Lucky for you @JoshuaGoldberg, but in my case I even cannot delete chaches folder. what could be issue?

Comment: I'd deleted .gradle/caches/** and it works again. Strange thing is that I only use the ./gradlew which shouldn't use the local gradle version right?

Comment: @BenGroot AFAIK all gradle daemons with the same gradle version share the same cache (if not explicitly forced otherwise), no matter where they were started from.

Answer (score 18):

For Windows machine:

Open Task Manager(Ctrl-Alt-Delete and check Process)

-> If you run two instance of android studio, Close One (End Task)

-> Then close OpenJDK Platform Binary

-> Gradle sync now on AndroidStudio and it will work now

Comment: This worked for me. But in my case, I had two instances of open JDK open, and one Android Studio.

Answer (score 13):

Just **kill java.exe process** fix my problem.

**-- Edit --**

if not fixed then:

- **kill OpenJdkPlatform proccess.**

if not fixed then:

- **remove all ".lock" file from .gradle directory** and sub directories (windows: C:\Users\Username\.gradle).

if not fixed then:

- **rename or delete .gradle directory** and try again.

Comment: After reading your answer, I deleted the .gradle directory and now after re-compiling the app is completely broken.

Comment: After reading your answer, I deleted the .gradle directory and now after re-compiling the app is completely broken.
Font sizes have increased, padding has increase, getting random validation errors.
What can I do now?

Comment: Are you sure just delete .gradle directory? remove .gradle must doesn't have any side effect to your app code. it is just gradle cache and if you compile your app again. gradle will download necessary files. try clean build.

Answer (score 13):

That Gradle failure message is usually followed by the relevant process IDs, so it would be

```
Gradle sync failed: Timeout waiting to lock daemon addresses registry [...].
It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.

Owner PID: 1234
Our PID: 5678
Owner Operation: ...
```

In order to unlock, just kill the owner process:

```
sudo kill -9 1234
```

Comment: i got Owner PID: Unknown. How to find that?

Answer (score 11):

**For MAC machines**

Please open the "Activity Monitor" and select the "memory" option and force quiet the Android studio and other running java processes, it will solve this issue.

Comment: works for me when running with intelliJ on Mac

Comment: This is also important to do for AppCode (I'm looking at you Kotlin Multiplatform project)

Answer (score 8):

This may be happening because there is more than just once instance of Android Studio.

Comment: Agreed, opening multi-window android studio and simultaneously syncing caused this issue as well

Comment: @Justin well spotted

Answer (score 8):

On windows . In *Android Studio* open **Terminal** window (used to  start in project's root folder)   and tipe in

```
 .\gradlew --stop
```

mine  responded:

```
Welcome to Gradle 7.3.3!

Here are the highlights of this release:
 - Easily declare new test suites in Java projects
 - Support for Java 17
 - Support for Scala 3

For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/release-notes.html

Stopping Daemon(s)
1 Daemon stopped
```

And now it plays ok with  builds and runs as previously

Answer (score 6):

I could be late but look like quick and efficient solution.

Execute following steps.

1. Execute `ps -ef | grep gradle`
2. Open terminal and move to **~/.gradle/caches** path
3. Execute `find ~/.gradle -type f -name "*.lock" | while read f; do rm $f; done`
4. Delete `.gradle` and `.idea` folder from Android studio.

It's done.

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the same issue in my project but I resolved this by invalidating the project, so follow these steps in the android studio

`File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...`

Android studio will restart and your problem should be fixed.

Comment: Worked also for IntelliJ with a normal java project!

Comment: Also worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue on mac:

take care, that your project is NOT on an external hard disk. The location of your project must be on the hard disk with your operating system.

(Building an Ionic app)

Comment: It seems that in my case, the problem is this too. The other day I transferred the project to an external drive.

Comment: This solved the issue for me as well. On Windows.

Comment: I had a problem with the file system of the SSD external disk on the MacBook Pro m2 system, which was ExFAT. The MacBook internal disk worked fine. This seems to be the biggest reason for generating the dreg files on MacOS.

Answer (score 5):

Having the same issue on a Mac, none of the above worked for me. What worked , though, was opening the Activity Monitor and closing a running java process. I also noticed that an .hprof file was generated, which I deleted. After that, I ran my project and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

press `CTRL + SHIFT + ESC` to open task manager now find `OpenJDK` and kill it goto where the error is pointing to like

```
D:\.gradle\daemon\4.10.1\registry.bin.lock
```

delete the file and resynce and you're good to go.

Answer (score 3):

Just delete yours `.gradle` folder inside `android` folder

If it is not available in your `File Explorer(WINDOWS)` or `Finder(MAC)`

**For Windows :**
go to `view` option and check `show hidden files`

**For Mac**

just press `cmd + shift + .`

Now run your app.

Answer (score 2):

For Windows OS:

I figured it had something to do with a lock file so i simply went to .gradle\buildOutputCleanup in the project folder and deleted the cache.properties.lock file and rebuilt the project. It was working perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Along with the top answers here, you need to figure out why the gradle processes exit without releasing the locks to fix it permanently.

In my case, I did all *.lock file deletions and Android Studio's Invalidate Cache option. But the problem kept coming back.

Running gradlew manually in the terminal showed me that gradle processes prematurely exit when the JVM heap space is exhausted. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59624003/daemon-is-stopping-immediately-jvm-garbage-collector-thrashing-and-after-running) helped to fix it.

```sh
./gradlew build #to detect what crashes gradle processes
./gradlew --stop #to stop any running gradle processes
```

After fixing the problem (eg: heap exhausted)

```sh
find .gradle/ -type f -name "*.lock" -delete #delete lock files
./gradlew build #Try building the project
```

Answer (score 2):

go to android folder and run.

```
 ./gradlew --stop
```

That's  all using mac

Answer (score 1):

I was too stuck with the same thing. But it was sorted soon. Just delete the file:

> `D:\.gradle\daemon\6.1.1\registry.bin.lock`

also, I've ended OpenJDK from task manager. Idk it helped or not but both of them solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**For Mac users on first Gradle sync**

I had the same issue when cloning from GitLab using IntelliJ.
In fact, as mentioned here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53269914/2231299
you need to specify an internal hard disk.

So here were the steps in my case:

• Clone locally

• Wait for 1st gradle syncing to perform

• move directory to external hard disk

• reopen project at new location, and then gradle should work fine, even on external hard disk.

Comments:
Don't be afraid to re-commit if it looks like the files have some changes. It might just be indentation or line breaks issues, since your external disk might have a different format than your original mac disk.

Answer (score 0):

It was not necessary for me to remove any files to fix this error.

The issue I had is that Gradle instances had hung and were 6 command prompt entries in my task list that were spawned by Java.

Forcing the command prompt instances to close allowed me to continue work as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Its Work for me for 
Problem:-

> "Error:Timeout waiting to lock jars It is currently in use by another Gradle instance. Owner PID: 6896 Our PID: 5048 Owner Operation: Our operation: Lock"

Solution:-

1. close the Android Studio and  Open Task manager and end the process java.exe
2. open the derectory ....gradle\caches.
3. Delete the jar2.lock file.
4. Open android Studion and clean the project.

Answer (score 0):

Have tried all this answers, including kill java process, delete .gradle in HOME_DIR and in project dir, restarted Android Studio, and even restarted OS.

It started to work normally only after I launched gradle sync.

Answer (score 0):

**Very simple solution:**

no need to kill `Android Studio` , just Kill `OpenJdkPlatform` process,
then delete the `.lock` file located in:

```
rootProject/.gradle/<version>/taskHistory
```

Answer (score 0):

While killing the process and/or removing the lock file works, Gradle should be able to handle this on its own, **solving the problem permanently**. [This problem report](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/timeout-waiting-to-lock-file-hash-cache/21961) hints at the solution: Gradle cannot communicate with the gradle service.

Have a look at your local network firewall. In my case,

- allowing outbound traffic from 127.0.0.1 to 127.0.0.1,

  ```
  sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -s 127.0.0.1 -d 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
  ```
- allowing incoming traffic from 127.0.0.1

  ```
  sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1 -p udp -j ACCEPT
  ```

solved the issue. A discussion of a similar problem [at github](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/851).

> And, Please refer any link to improve my knowledge on Gradle Build system in Android.

The [udacity gradle course](https://en.udacity.com/course/gradle-for-android-and-java--ud867), if you have some time.

Answer (score 0):

open terminal and move to project path then run depending on the operation system: 
gradlew clean or ./gradlew clean

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and i did two steps and it became solved.

1. My JDK was not installed on Mac (i forgot to install) i installed it.
2. I deleted all items from caches folder located in this path /Users/icon_developer/.gradle/ and rebuilt the project. 
   It worked!

Answer (score 0):

**For Windows Users:**

*That Gradle failure message is usually followed by the relevant process IDs, so it would be
Gradle sync failed: Timeout waiting to lock daemon addresses registry [...].
It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.*

```
Owner PID: 8080
Our PID: 89765
Owner Operation: ...
In order to unlock, just kill the owner process:

taskkill /PID 8080 /F
taskkill /PID 89765 /F
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the culprit was restrictive firewall, part of the antivirus system.

According to the https://discuss.gradle.org/t/timeout-waiting-to-lock-file-hash-cache/21961/2 and https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/50954#issuecomment-576772154, [gradle-issue-8750](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/8750#issuecomment-845284035), gradle server is keeping the lock and releases it on request of other gradle process. The communication goes over UDP socket on localhost. Thus if there is a firewall blocking this communication, gradle keeps file locks and other gradle processes cannot continue.

Try disabling AV / firewall to see if problem vanishes. Then run gradle as following to get better insight what is going on.

```
gradle --debug --no-daemon
```

The debug log shows owner of the lock, if the problem persists, kill the owner of the lock.

```
2021-05-20T19:32:41.105+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] The file lock is held by a different Gradle process (pid: 67494, lockId: 628651820260732672). Pinged owner at port 58442
2021-05-20T19:32:42.330+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] The file lock is held by a different Gradle process (pid: 67494, lockId: 628651820260732672). Pinged owner at port 58442
```

Then `kill -9 67494` terminates the owner and releases the lock.

Otherwise after a while gradle terminates with an error (stating here so it is easy to find):

```
* What went wrong:
Gradle could not start your build.
 > Could not create service of type ResourceSnapshotterCacheService using GradleUserHomeServices.createResourceSnapshotterCacheService().
   > Timeout waiting to lock file hash cache (/Users/myusername/.gradle/caches/6.9/fileHashes). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.
     Owner PID: 67494
     Our PID: 68313
     Owner Operation: 
     Our operation: 
     Lock file: /Users/myusername/.gradle/caches/6.9/fileHashes/fileHashes.lock
```

Answer (score 0):

Citing a scenario to @Sean Stayns's answer in case it helps anyone: If you're saving your projects in a Google Drive folder -- don't. Simply moving the project(s) over to the local drive resolves this problem.

In the case we were trying to solve, were were also getting the "It is currently in use by another Gradle instance" error and nothing we tried here worked. The process ID was unknown as well. It didn't immediately occur to me to ask where the project was being saved, so in case anyone new to Android Dev is saving their projects to a Google Drive folder, just move over to your local drive. I would have just left this as a comment in @Sean Stayns's answer, but I can't comment. Hopefully it benefits someone.

Answer (score 0):

**For Mac Users:**

you need to give gradle permission:

```
sudo gradle
```

Answer (score 0):

> org.gradle.cache.LockTimeoutException: Timeout waiting to lock journal
> cache (C:\Users\unknown.gradle\caches\journal-1). It is currently in
> use by another Gradle instance

I was facing the same issue and I fixed it by opening Task Manger and check running instance of "OpenJDK Platform binary" in background processes except Android Stduio just "End Task" this task and work for me

Answer (score 0):

Make your `$JAVA_HOME` to point to the same **JDK** version as your **Android Studio**.

[image]

All kudos to Vairavan Srinivasan from [Medium](https://medium.com/@debuggingisfun/gradle-timeout-waiting-to-lock-cf3cac516946)

Answer (score 0):

With old Flutter project, run with newer version Flutter SDK. You can follow my steps below:

Go to `android/build.gradle` update `kotlin` and `gradle` to new version:

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10' >> ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.20'
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1' >> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
```

Next go to `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` update:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-all.zip >> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6-all.zip
```

After

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
// remove lock file
rm /Volumes/T7 Shield/FlutterCodeCanyon/flutter-tiktok-triller-clone-short-video-streaming-mobile-app-for-android-ios/flutter_app/android/.gradle/7.6/dependencies-accessors/dependencies-accessors.lock
// stop gradle
cd android
./gradlew --stop
// or
ps -ef | grep gradle
kill -9 123
```

Finally run Flutter project again

---

If you run Project in exFAT SSD on MacOS, maybe error below:

[Gradle Faild on ExFat SSD](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/4329)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows, Go to task manager and kill JDK processes.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For Windows Users, hit the below command in the terminal -

```
./gradlew --status
```

Check All the running PIDs and kill/Stop the require PID using below command

```
./gradlew --stop
```

Answer (score -1):

everyone finally,
    I have complete solution

```
Error :- Timeout Gradle cashe its running in other gradle


distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists

Please add this Line in Wrapper.Propertis and Sync now
After Sync the project When 
Invalidthcast\restart   to get the requesting componants
```