# Gradle java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, out-of-memory, metaspace

Currently i am working on Spring boot 2.1 project configured with Gradle 5.2.1. But i got out of memory error when building project and could not understand the exact reason.

Please find the attached log

```
Caused by: org.gradle.cache.CacheOpenException: Could not open proj generic class cache for build file '/Users/mac/project/build.gradle' (/Users/mac/.gradle/caches/5.2.1/scripts/eajdx6l75dt1ypyljdsfupplm/proj/proj3ca90766b0adfce53d4b035e7e9dc5fe).
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.open(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:80)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.open(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:42)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory.doOpen(DefaultCacheFactory.java:94)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory.open(DefaultCacheFactory.java:68)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheRepository$PersistentCacheBuilder.open(DefaultCacheRepository.java:118)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler$RemapBuildScriptsAction.execute(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:421)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler$RemapBuildScriptsAction.execute(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:390)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler$ProgressReportingInitializer.execute(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:175)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler$ProgressReportingInitializer.execute(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:155)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryCache$Initializer.initialize(DefaultPersistentDirectoryCache.java:98)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.FixedSharedModeCrossProcessCacheAccess$1.run(FixedSharedModeCrossProcessCacheAccess.java:85)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.doWriteAction(DefaultFileLockManager.java:207)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.writeFile(DefaultFileLockManager.java:197)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.FixedSharedModeCrossProcessCacheAccess.open(FixedSharedModeCrossProcessCacheAccess.java:83)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.open(DefaultCacheAccess.java:142)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.open(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:78)
        ... 133 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First kill the Java(TM) Platform SE binary process and then delete the whole /Users//.gradle/caches folder which will allow Gradle commands to work once again.

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32513740/gradle-build-failure-could-not-open-proj-class-cache-for-build-file) thread might help you.

Comment: In my case it was enough to just shutdown AS and kill the Java process, then started AS again and no error.