# cordova build cannot agree on Java version

Tags: java, android, cordova

`$ cordova build android –release`
When `JAVA_HOME` points to old `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_261` - I get:
**Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.**
When `JAVA_HOME` points to new `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.2` - I get:
**Requirements check failed for JDK 8 ('1.8.*')! Detected version: 17.0.2**
How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Older versions of cordova-android required Java 8, which was requirements from the parts & versions of Android SDK cordova used. There is a Android SDK / cordova-android version mismatch in your environment.

As of cordova-android@10 (current version at the time of writing), the Java 8 restriction was opened up to allow Java 11 as cordova-android was updated to use more modern versions of the Android SDK which consequentially requires Java 11.

> Requirements check failed for JDK 8 ('1.8.*')

Not sure which cordova-android version you're running but this error definitely means you aren't running cordova-android@10, so I'd suggest to update the cordova-android platform.

```
cordova platform remove android
cordova platform add android@10
```

I'd also suggest ensuring you're running cordova cli verison 10 or later as well. (Checkable via `cordova -v`)

Comment: Thanks. I noticed cordova 11 released recently (https://cordova.apache.org/news/2021/12/21/cordova-cli-11.0.0-release.html) - Isn't it better to go directly for this?

Comment: Ideally yes. cordova cli 11 actually pins cordova-android 10 by default (that is if you don't specify the version it will install version 10 of cordova-android)

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance: Is there a difference between npm uninstall/install and cordova platform remove/add? I did the former and still getting the "Requirements check failed for JDK 8"...

Comment: Yes. npm install/uninstall simply adds/removes the packages from your node_modules. the cordova command actually manages the cordova project. cordova uses NPM behind the scenes to add/remove packages.

Comment: Well, after the cordova platform remove/add - the java error has gone. 
I have a different error now though, but that's for a different question. 
Thanks!

Comment: It appears that following the cordova platform remove/add - the platforms\android\gradle folder has gone. My new problem seems to be related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58293436/could-not-compile-settings-gradle-react-native

Answer (score 0):

You should download the latest version

Comment: But jdk-17.0.2 IS the latest version...