# I'm getting this error everytime i try to run the code in my android device. I'm a beginner in app dev. I'm using VScode

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not open proj generic class cache for build file 'C:\flutter\basicappone\android\app\build.gradle' (C:\Users(myusername).gradle\caches\6.7\scripts\dzfm7roiq3666tjbu4va561d9).
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 60

Comment: does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32513740/gradle-build-failure-could-not-open-proj-class-cache-for-build-file

Answer (score 0):

I just hit this also on checkout of a new project.

The project was using Gradle 6.3 via the gradle wrapper (`cat ./gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`) but the JDK I had configured was Version 16 (`java --version`).

Per [the Gradle compatability matrix](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html) I saw that Java Version 16 is not supported until Gradle version 7....

Per your question (`....gradle\caches\6.7...`) i assume gradle v6.7 in your case, and so I believe your options are the same as mine....

...Either:

1. configure a compatible JDK for the project (java 14 or earlier for me, 15 for you i think)
2. update the gradle wrapper for the project to gradle version 7