# When I type the command npx react-native run-android I get 1 error and 1 warning and the warning is displayed next to the terminal window in vscode

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator

When I type the command npx react-native run-android I get 1 error and 1 warning and the warning is displayed next to the terminal window in vscode.

+ The color of the file name changes to green and a U mark is displayed.

## 1. error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.

I thought I just had to install the Android Studio emulator.

```
PS C:\Users\gogum\OneDrive\바탕 화면\nomadreact\AwesomeProject> npx react-native run-android
info Starting JS server...
��d�� ��θ� ã; �� ��4ϴ�.
info Launching emulator...
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
info Installing the app...
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 2 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'AwesomeProject'.
> Could not open cp_proj generic class cache for build file 'C:\Users\gogum\OneDrive\���� ȭ��\nomadreact\AwesomeProject\android\build.gradle' (C:\Users\gogum\.gradle\caches\7.5.1\scripts\a5ygbdadaeeg0rkha3nsmbkg1).
   > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 64

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 44s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'AwesomeProject'.
> Could not open cp_proj generic class cache for build file 'C:\Users\gogum\OneDrive\���� ȭ��\nomadreact\AwesomeProject\android\build.gradle' (C:\Users\gogum\.gradle\caches\7.5.1\scripts\a5ygbdadaeeg0rkha3nsmbkg1).
   > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 64

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 44s

    at makeError (C:\Users\gogum\OneDrive\바탕 화면\nomadreact\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at C:\Users\gogum\OneDrive\바탕 화면\nomadreact\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\gogum\OneDrive\바탕 화면\nomadreact\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:82:7)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\gogum\OneDrive\바탕 화면\nomadreact\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:108:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

[error1 - emulater error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gb7rl.png)

Tried:

Android Studio's Virtual Device Manager

=> I opened virtual device manager in android studio and created Nexus 5X API 33 (tiramisu).

But the error still appeared. What should I do? help!

Comment: Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32513740/gradle-build-failure-could-not-open-proj-class-cache-for-build-file