# Timeout waiting to lock artifact cache (/path/to/.gradle/caches/modules-2). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, mozilla, mach

Not sure if this question is for stackoverflow or superuser

EDIT: superuser doesn't even have a gradle tag, so I'm guessing this is for stackoverflow

Hi i am trying to run ./mach gradle app:test to test bug fixes in mozillas code

When I run it I get this error

`Timeout waiting to lock artifact cache (/home/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.`

I get the same error when running `./mach gradle app:checkstyle` so I assume I would get this with and `gradle` command

I've checked to see what daemons where running with `service --status-all` but there i nothing there with the word gradle in it

The other questions I've looked at had answers that say to run `gradle --stop` to check if daemons are running. When I run that command it says `Stopping daemon(s)` and hangs

How can I fix this? I have tried closing and re-opening the terminal.

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21523508/it-is-currently-in-use-by-another-gradle-instance

Answer (score 11):

Error message

```
* What went wrong:
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':runtime'.
   > Timeout waiting to lock artifact cache (\Users\username\.gradle\caches\modules-2). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.
     Owner PID: 10736
     Our PID: 204
     Owner Operation: resolve configuration ':classpath'
     Our operation:
     Lock file: \Users\username\.gradle\caches\modules-2\modules-2.lock

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

it's occours when you terminate gradle build task by  Ctrl+C or Crtl+Z .

```
rm your_path/modules-2.lock
```

Answer (score 6):

1. Close Android Studio and open task manager and end the process `java.exe` or openJDK platform `binary.exe`.
2. Open the directory `gradle\caches\modules-2\modules-2.lock` file delete
3. Open Android Studio and check it.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, this problem occur when `yarn or npm run android` is terminated at the terminal by `Ctrl + Z`. What i did to solve it was to delete `/modules-2.lock` by running `rm yourpath/modules-2.lock`. 
Then after that, re-run `yarn run android` or react-native run-android``` and your build will be successfull

Answer (score 0):

go to file menu

select invalidate cache and restart

on starting android again 
go to file 
select sync with file 
then once done
sync with gradle

Answer (score 0):

1. Close Android Studio, IntelliJ, or the JetBrains IDEA which you are using.
2. If you are using a Windows machine then End the process java.exe or binary.exe from the task manager. Else If you are using a Mac machine (UNIX) then clean the process from the activity monitor
3. Then navigate to the 'gradle\caches\modules-2' (or the appearing path in the console) and then delete the .lock file
4. Now try running the application.