# Gradle :Could not create service of type FileHasher

Tags: gradle

I'm using Gradle to build a java project. 
When I run any task (assemble, test).
I get randomly an error :

```
Could not create service of type FileHasher using 
GradleUserHomeScopeServices.createCachingFileHasher()
```

Did any one had the same issue before?

Gradle V:3.5

java 8

I'm using the java plugin.

Thanks,

Comment: as a workaround, I deleted the lock files. and it works

Comment: I would suggest marking [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61012434/4266287) as the selected one

Comment: gradlew --stop solve the problem

Answer (score 58):

I was facing the same because I accidentally hit ctrl+z during build, and then the error was the same as yours.

I tried to remove the lock file but it didn't solve the problem.

Then I find all the process related to gradle by `ps aux | grep gradle`, and then `kill -9 <pid>` them all. The build backed to normal.

Comment: This works but also a bit brutal. Can also run `gradle --stop` to have the daemon stopped gracefully - https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:stopping_an_existing_daemon

Comment: Activity monitor helped to identify the tasks after the ps aux | grep gradle, this helped reassure me that I was killing the right tasks.

Comment: Sadly `gradle --stop` didn't work for me.  Only killing those processes solved this problem.

Comment: the problem for me was because I tried to compile without java installed in my machine, dann! stupid computer, hahahaha

Answer (score 33):

In your terminal type this:

```
./gradlew build
```

and the outcome would be:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not create service of type FileHasher using GradleUserHomeScopeServices.createCachingFileHasher().
> Timeout waiting to lock file hash cache (/Users/zra/.gradle/caches/4.1-rc-1/fileHashes). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.
  Owner PID: 17571
  Our PID: 26055
  Owner Operation: 
  Our operation: 
  Lock file: /Users/xxx/.gradle/caches/4.1-rc-1/fileHashes/fileHashes.lock
```

now do:

```
rm /Users/xxx/.gradle/caches/4.1-rc-1/fileHashes/fileHashes.lock
```

and build again.

P.S replace xxx with whatever username you've.

Answer (score 25):

What worked for me was removing the lock file like suggested in the answer above: `rm /Users/xxx/.gradle/caches/4.1-rc-1/fileHashes/fileHashes.lock` and also killing the IDLE processes by running the command

```
./gradlew --status
```

It generates a list of gradle processes with status like

```
  PID STATUS   INFO
 23580 IDLE     5.2.1
 23860 IDLE     5.2.1
 19058 STOPPED  (stop command received)
```

Then kill one of the idle processes by `kill <PID>` and run the gradle build again.

Answer (score 19):

One simple cause is that gradle daemon is not started with the same environment variable.
I had the same issue while changing       the gradle user home.

Simply stop the daemon:

```
gradle --stop
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Unlike the popular answer saying delete the lock files.

Answer (score 6):

change the ownership of `.gradle/` using the following command:

```sh
sudo chown -R <USERNAME> .gradle/
```

Answer (score 2):

If the OS is Windows. 
Try this: gradlew build
Find de PID Process

[image]

And in CMD execute this command

```
TASKKILL /F /PID  #PID
```

Comment: This article is util

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find this info elsewhere, posting in case it helps someone:

I had the same issue while running Android Studio on ChromeOS (on Chromebook).

I had shared a Google Drive folder with Linux (by selecting a folder, right-clicking and selecting **Share with Linux**) and created my project there. Build failed with this error, and removing the lock file did nothing for me.

Problem was resolved for me by re-creating the project under a 'Linux folder'.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was keeping the entire project in a folder managed by [Google Drive Stream](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9178853?hl=en). Since that's a very rudimentary filesystem, Android Studio (or Git or Gradle, I can't tell which) was trying to do something on the FS that Google Drive Stream doesn't allow.

I simply moved the project onto my local drive and that fixed it!

Comment: I had same issue with project stored on WSL2 directory. I guess NFS doesn't have support required locking methods.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when I tried to execute `./gradlew` from WSL2 ubuntu.
As suggested by @user16115, I stopped the running gradle in my host machine (windows machine) by issuing command `gradlew.bat --stop`.

After stopping the gradle in my host machine, I issued the same command `./gradlew` in WSL2, gradle worked as expected.

ps: I have mounted my `C:/` drive into WSL2 ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

As for me it happened on  my comp running **Windows OS** . So I realized that my projects folder is located within OneDrive folder. So you have to either move the project outside the OneDrive one or merely **turn the OneDrive on**.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux environment, kill gradle process by following command

ps -eaf | grep gradle
kill -9

This resolved issue

Answer (score -1):

This was same problem for me before some days and now only it's your or the user reading this solution.

1. Uninstall full android studio (means- 'after uninstall from control panel, delete folders of Android Studio,')
   folders to be deleted:

   C:\Program Files -> Android,
   C:\Users{user folder name} -> .android & .gradle & {other folders related to Android Studio}
2. Reinstall form it's `.exe` and make sure your PC in connected with internet and with proper speed.
3. Download all SDK files as mention  in that and keep downloading in Android Studio only. [do not download form other source- otherwise it will show errors, be careful]
4. Click on new project and select empty project and give the name and click on finish.

you will redirect to another window and than the main thing starts that is installation of GRADLE so for this you should have high connectivity of internet and that it will download automatically and and and now your are ready to go.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and the solution was to login with the correct user and then run gradle. I was logged in with a user that didn't had rights to run the tasks.

Answer (score -1):

- I just moved a project from `Download` folder (on Mac) to another one
- If you try to build an inner project - try to go to root project and call

```
./gradlew <moduleName>:<command>
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest solution in my case wast to run

In case of linux

```
sudo ./gradlew bundleRelease
```

if windows then login with the user who has highest privileges.

Because this error occurred due to insufficient permissions