# Flutter VSCode : Debug error:Could not create service of type FileHasher using BuildSessionServices.createFileHasher()

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, dart, visual-studio-code

Trying to start programming Dart in Flutter. I wanted to work with VSCode instead of Android Studio, but when debug session starts I get the following problems.

**I tried everything** here in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45177977/gradle-could-not-create-service-of-type-filehasher) such as **deleting the caches**, **deleting lock file**, **kill PID Task in cmd**, but nothing works.

However, I'm able to run the test app in Android Studio, but still, I wanted to learn via VSCode. It will be great if you can share any suggestion that might help :)

Thanks!

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Gradle could not start your build.
> Could not create service of type FileHasher using BuildSessionServices.createFileHasher().
   > Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Flutter SDK: windows 1.17.1 (from the website)
Android Studio: 3.6.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Able to solve my own problem. Apparently, when I first sync the demo app in VSCode, it started to download package from gradle 5.62, whereas 6.4 available in my machine. Which then I changed the setting and distributionUrl thingy to that version 6.4 . And when I started to run it, that error stated in the question surfaced.

What I did was:

1. Go to project level .gradle file (app> android> .gradle)
2. Delete the file of gralde of the other version
3. Go to the gradle folder of the 6.4 version, delete the lock file in caches/filehashes
4. restart

Answer (score 0):

In android/app/build.gradle
Try changing minSdkVersion to 21
I had same issue this worked

Answer (score 0):

For Windows machine:

Open Task Manager(Ctrl-Alt-Delete and check Process)

-> Close All instances of Android Studio/VS Code (End Task)

-> Close Emulator (if Running)

-> Then close OpenJDK Platform Binary

it will work now