# flutter --stacktrace error and can not show the app

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I am developing flutter with VS Code and while compiling I get the following error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory().

Could not create service of type FileHasher using BuildSessionScopeServices.createFileSnapshotter().

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

then I ran the project with Android Studio but I get a similar error.

What other solution could there be other than starting a new project?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gradle Could not create service of type InitScriptHandler using BuildScopeServices.createInitScriptHandler()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30840526/gradle-could-not-create-service-of-type-initscripthandler-using-buildscopeservic)

Comment: sorry but didn't work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gradle: Could not not create service of type FileHasher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45177977/gradle-could-not-create-service-of-type-filehasher/46094804)

Comment: thanks for your reply.
As a solution I manually updated a few packages in the pubspec file and it was fixed,
There is an answer on the site, but I guess you need to constantly try