# Could not connect to the Gradle daemon. while running 'flutter run'

Tags: android, flutter

I tried running 'flutter run' on newly created flutter project but it stucks in Resolving dependencies and got below errors in logs.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on ASUS X00DDA in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...                                       1.2s
Resolving dependencies...
* Error running Gradle:
Exit code 1 from: C:\Users\username\Desktop\Project\myprojectr\android\gradlew.bat app:properties:
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 14 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not connect to the Gradle daemon.
Daemon uid: 6a5529f2-392b-4727-b66f-78a2fab605bf with diagnostics:
Daemon pid: 14840
  log file: C:\Users\arjay24\.gradle\daemon\4.1\daemon-14840.out.log
----- Last  20 lines from daemon log file - daemon-14840.out.log -----
15:00:39.882 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] DaemonExpirationPeriodicCheck running
15:00:39.888 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
15:00:39.889 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
15:00:39.890 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
15:00:39.891 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
15:00:39.891 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
15:00:39.892 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
15:00:39.893 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
15:00:39.893 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
15:00:39.893 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
15:00:49.885 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] DaemonExpirationPeriodicCheck running
15:00:49.885 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
15:00:49.886 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
15:00:49.886 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
15:00:49.887 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
15:00:49.887 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
15:00:49.888 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
15:00:49.889 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
15:00:49.889 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] The file lock is held by a different Gradle process (pid: 13900, operation: ). Will attempt to ping owner at port 61789
15:00:49.889 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] The file lock is held by a different Gradle process. I was unable to read on which port the owner listens for lock access requests.
----- End of the daemon log -----


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
```

It's weird because the other day it works perfectly and I haven't changed or installed anything.

Comment: What you can try is `flutter clean` `flutter upgrade` and `Invalidate caches and restart`; if you are using Android Studio/IntelliJ.

Comment: I am using visual studio code and android studio for IDEs both shows the same error. I already tried flutter clean and flutter upgrade but no success.

Comment: Sounds basic but did you try to restart your pc so adb etc restarts itself?

Comment: @Bostrot Yes restart the pc and kill  and then restart adb but still exist. :'(

Comment: Is there some news on the matter? I have a similar problem on Windows as well. And it is somehow has started today...

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: If you have a vpn with a kill switch, try turning it off that worked for me

Answer (score 12):

I solved it by disconnecting from my VPN. Seems weird but it worked :-)

Comment: One Line answers can always go in the comments!

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me!

Comment: In case of ProtonVPN turning KillSwitch off works as well.

Answer (score 0):

The issue doesn't seem to be caused by Flutter. Inspecting the logs, the instance couldn't connect to the Gradle daemon due to "The file lock is held by a different Gradle process". If you're still having this issue, could you try [removing the lock files in the Gradle cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32783447/2497859) and try running the app again?

Answer (score 0):

I also had incorrect path of distributionUrl in your_root_directory/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

It worked after correcting the path:
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip

Comment: While I agree with you, I think, this should be a comment on the initial question, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I got an idea from @F.Tepel answer, After uninstalling my antivirus my issue was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I usually solve this issue by running

```
./gradlew --stop
```

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, for me the issue was no internet connection. I've recently modified some Gradle configuration and apparently it needed to download some stuff from internet.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue.
I solved the issue by upgrading the gradle by changing the `distributionUrl` in the `your_root_directory/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file.

You can refer [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html#sec:adding_wrapper) for the instructions to upgrade gradle