# Daemon is stopping immediately JVM garbage collector thrashing and after running out of JVM memory

Tags: java, gradle

When I build multi module java project using gradle 6.0,when I add >30 modules.Throw this error:

```
Gradle Daemon started in 2 s 267 ms

> Configure project :soa-misc
"/opt/dabai/tools/jdk1.8.0_211/jre/lib/ext/"
null
Expiring Daemon because JVM heap space is exhausted
Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build after running out of JVM memory
Expiring Daemon because JVM heap space is exhausted
Expiring Daemon because JVM heap space is exhausted
Expiring Daemon because JVM heap space is exhausted
Expiring Daemon because JVM heap space is exhausted
Expiring Daemon because JVM heap space is exhausted
Expiring Daemon because JVM heap space is exhausted
Expiring Daemon because JVM heap space is exhausted
Expiring Daemon because JVM heap space is exhausted
Expiring Daemon because JVM heap space is exhausted
Expiring Daemon because JVM heap space is exhausted
Expiring Daemon because JVM heap space is exhausted
Daemon is stopping immediately JVM garbage collector thrashing and after running out of JVM memory
```

What I am tried to add parameter in my `$HOME/.gradle/gradle.properties`:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx8096m -XX:MaxPermSize=8096m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

But the problem not solved,what should I do to fix?

Comment: Did you stop the existing gradle daemons after modifying `gradle.properties`?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I add `gradle.properties` file in my root project dir,and add this config:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096M
```

works. From the error message we can know the Daemon JVM spcace exhausted. This is the Gradle [official docuemnt](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html) about this config:

> Specifies the JVM arguments used for the Gradle Daemon. The setting is
> particularly useful for configuring JVM memory settings for build
> performance. This does not affect the JVM settings for the Gradle
> client VM. The default is -Xmx512m "-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m".

Comment: If it doesn't work, also try adding `android:largeHeap="true"` in `<application` tag in `AndroidManifes.xml`

Comment: this was great when upgrading Gradle while going for Android Studio 4.0, thanks a bunch!

Comment: I have added the official document link so that you can know why change the config like this. @JCraine

Comment: @dolphin Thank you Dolphin! I deleted my comment to edit/resubmit right when you replied. I appreciate the follow up :)

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you can't modify the `gradle.properties` file for whatever reason (e.g. I modified a `gitlab-ci.yml` file's script for a CICD pipeline issue that couldn't be reproduced locally), you can use a command line flag (with a `-D` prefix) as referenced in the "official document" above by @Dolphin.

```
-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096M
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe it will help other users as well.

I received, somewhat, this error when I did a `gradlew clean` on the `android` directory and forgot to go back with `cd ..` and I run the command of starting the app inside `android` directory when it shouldn't.

The solution is to go back from `android` directory and run the start command in the root directory of your app.